# Sitecore dms - get all profiles for visitor

Tags: sitecore, profile, visitor-pattern, sitecore7.2, sitecore-dms

I tried to using 2 ways to get all profiles for visitor after login:

1. Using `Tracker.CurrentVisit` to get Profiles
2. Get visitor using `VisitorManager.GetVisitorByExternalUser()` then 
   get Profiles (`visitor.DataSet.Profiles`)

Both of them can't get any profile records. I checked `Profiles` table on `Analytics` database: this visitor had some profile record. So how get old profiles of visitor after login.

Thanks.

Comment: Which Sitecore version you use?

Comment: Are you expecting to see the accumulated profile scores from previous visits?

Comment: @Marek I am using sitecore v7.2

Comment: @Martin Not only profile stores I want to know how get all profiles for a visitor then i can do st with it. Has any function sirecore api tp support it ?

Comment: Try also Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Visitor.CurrentVisit.Profiles

Comment: If we use Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Visitor.CurrentVisit.Profiles, we will only get latest profile for visitor (current visit), not all profiles for visitor, right?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the following method `visitor.LoadAll();`